# Insert SQL with array

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-ajax

I have an array called `svg`. I want to insert this array into the database with ajax - how can I do the controller part of it? SQL also has 9 columns and I must insert SQL this columns

```
public void InsertTicket(string svg)
{
    List<string[,]>Ticket = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<string[,]>>(svg);
    GameTicket gameTicket = new GameTicket();

    foreach (var item in Ticket)
    {
        gameTicket.GameTicketRedNumber = 1;
    }

    _sql.GameTickets.Add(gameTicket);
    _sql.SaveChanges();
}
```

`svg` array is shown in this screenshot:

[image]

````
```  $('#confirm').click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: "/Main/InsertTicket",
            dataType: "json",
            traditional: true,
            data: { svg: JSON.stringify(svg) },
            success: function (data) {
                console.log("Success");
            },
            error: function () {
                console.log("error");
            }
        })
    })```
````

Comment: So what is the issue? do you have problem with mapping list string to columns?

Comment: ```  $('#confirm').click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: "/Main/InsertTicket",
            dataType: "json",
            traditional: true,
            data: { svg: JSON.stringify(svg) },
            success: function (data) {
                console.log("Success");
            },
            error: function () {
                console.log("error");
            }
        })
    })```  @SaeedEsmaeelinejad